# Sausages cooked?

Tags: sausages

I cooked some small pork sausages. They were slightly pink when removed from the pan. How do you know if they are cooked fully? I am worried I am going to make myself sick. I must have cooked them for more than 10 minutes, I had to remove the eggs from the pan, to avoid burning them. What is the objective way to know if these are cooked?

Comment: These were small sausages. (FYI)

Comment: Some (cheap) sausages stay rather pink, and temperature is the best way to be sure. Cooking then a bit more slowly might be a good idea, a lid can help with even cooking. We don't know what 7-8 means on your stove; some only go up to 6

Comment: Is there a way to know if they are cooked after the fact? Also, I can't seriously be expected to temperature probe all of them, how can you even be sure?

Comment: The ONLY objective way is to know the internal temperature.

Comment: Could 7-8 for 10+ minutes have been enough?

Comment: You can ask the question 100 different ways and the answer will still be to check the internal temperature.   You have been asked what 7-8 means and did not answer.  VTC

Comment: I very rarely measure the temperature of any food. And it would be fair to assume that those that look the same inside are the same inside, testing only 1. 10 minutes in an open pan might well not be enough even if they're burnt on the outside from cooking them too hot, but "10+" could mean all day.

Comment: When in doubt, split them open lengthwise and cook them cut side down for a few more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a 100% foolproof way besides temperature.

However, if you know from experience that sausages of this size cooked in this way for this length of time end up fully cooked, then you can be pretty confident these were too. You may also be able to gain some confidence by checking the texture, not just the color, and by checking for instructions on the package.